# Get start and stop of time period in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a following dataframe in pandas:

```
+----------+-------------------+---------------------+----------+------------+
| UserName | MainOperationName |  Submission_Ended   |  delta   | new period |
+----------+-------------------+---------------------+----------+------------+

| User1    | Record submission | 2017-07-31 00:08:25 | 00:00:00 | False      |
| User1    | Record submission | 2017-07-31 00:12:02 | 00:03:37 | False      |
| User1    | Record submission | 2017-07-31 00:14:51 | 00:02:49 | False      |
| User1    | Record submission | 2017-07-31 00:17:27 | 00:02:36 | False      |
| User1    | Record submission | 2017-07-31 00:23:42 | 00:06:15 | False      |
| User1    | Record submission | 2017-07-31 00:25:35 | 00:01:53 | False      |
| User1    | Record submission | 2017-07-31 00:26:01 | 00:00:26 | False      |
| User1    | Record submission | 2017-07-31 01:59:11 | 01:33:10 | True       |
| User1    | Record submission | 2017-07-31 02:00:37 | 00:01:26 | False      |
| User1    | Record submission | 2017-07-31 02:03:12 | 00:02:35 | False      |
| User1    | Record submission | 2017-07-31 02:21:22 | 00:18:10 | False      |
| User1    | Record submission | 2017-07-31 02:30:28 | 00:09:06 | False      |
| User1    | Record submission | 2017-07-31 02:36:03 | 00:05:35 | False      |
| User1    | Record submission | 2017-07-31 03:25:43 | 00:49:40 | True       |
+----------+-------------------+---------------------+----------+------------+
```

`Delta` column is just the difference between rows of `Submission_Ended`. Then `new period` is True when the difference is greater than 20 minutes. I think I would also force first row value to be True because it's when a new period starts. I assume that when the delta is smaller than that the user is using the application  otherwise he/she is having a break. I would like to visualize that with timeline/gantt chart (like in the last section [here](https://plot.ly/python/gantt/)). But for that I need to get start and stop of each period which in that case would be:

- start: 2017-07-31 00:08:25 ; stop: 2017-07-31 00:26:01
- start: 2017-07-31 01:59:11 ; stop: 2017-07-31 02:36:03
- start: 2017-07-31 03:25:43 ; stop: ...

Any idea how I could get that from data structured like that? Just to mention that in my real dataframe there are hundreds of users.

Comment: Could you create a column for session number which is the cumulative sum of new period (i.e. every true value starts a new session)? It would have to be done on a per user basis but you could then group by user and session number to get the start and end times.

Answer (score 0):

Taylor's comment was very useful. I did the following:

```
session_id = 0

def get_session_id(row):
    global session_id

    if row == True:
        session_id += 1
        return session_id
    else:
        return session_id

df_ben["session id"] = df_ben["new period"].apply(lambda row: get_session_id(row))
start_time = df_ben.groupby("session id").nth(0)["Submission_Ended"]
stop_time = df_ben.groupby("session id").nth(-1)["Submission_Ended"]
df_final = pd.DataFrame({"start":start_time, "stop":stop_time})
```

And my final result is this:

```
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|            |        start        |        stop         |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| session id |                     |                     |
| 1          | 2017-07-31 00:08:25 | 2017-07-31 00:26:01 |
| 2          | 2017-07-31 01:59:11 | 2017-07-31 02:36:03 |
| 3          | 2017-07-31 03:25:43 | 2017-07-31 03:48:40 |
| 4          | 2017-07-31 04:12:03 | 2017-07-31 04:12:03 |
| 5          | 2017-07-31 04:36:09 | 2017-07-31 05:23:26 |
| 6          | 2017-07-31 05:59:04 | 2017-07-31 06:24:34 |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

So I can work with that!

Now I only don't like the way I assigned the `session_id` using `global` statement. Any idea how to do it in a neater way?